# Returning to Activity after a specified period of time

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I would like to return to specified `Activity` from each other `Activity` after specified period of idle time. What should I use: `Service`, `AlarmManager` or maybe something else?

Comment: I think you should use countdowntimer. It's simple. here is nice example.. http://adf.ly/KLVy7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want this to work only for your activities (not from background etc.) just use [TimerTask](http://www.android-ever.com/2012/07/android-timertask.html) in every activity of yours (well, in a superclass to avoid duplication). There's no point in putting up a Service for that.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pending Intent, refer this link ...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a service, or alarmmanager, you can use timertask, or i would suggest handler.
Handler.postdelayed. Its a better option.